# how to get the text from user input then set it in to the condition in html template?

Tags: html, django

I'm doing a lab creating the web view to access the data from mysql, so I have some config below:

student\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Student

# Create your views here.
def show(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()
    student_dict = {'student':students}
    return render(request, "show.html",student_dict)

def search(request):
    data = request.POST.get('name')
    print(data)
    return render(request, "search.html")
```

student\templates\search.html

```
   <h1>input your name then press submit button</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

student\templates\show.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Django CRUD Operations</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Roll</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for stud in student %}  
      <tr>
        {% if stud.fname == 'abc' %}   # I would like to make an input box for user can input here
        <td>{{stud.id}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.roll}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.sclass}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.fname}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.lname}}</td>
        {% endif %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %} 
    </tbody>
</table>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

student\urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
 
from . import views 
 
urlpatterns = [ 
     path('show/', views.show),
]
```

how to get "data" taken from input box when user submit in search.html template , then assign it into  {% if stud.fname == data %} in show.html template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the input text with a form. Then pass this text to template as context.

*student/views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Student
# Create your views here.
def show(request):
    input_text = request.POST.get('my_input', None)
    students = Student.objects.all()
    context = {
        'student':students,
        'input_text': input_text
    }
    return render(request, "show.html", context)
```

*student/templates/show.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Django CRUD Operations</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1> User Input </h1>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="my_input">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form> 


<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Roll</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for stud in student %}  
      <tr>
        {% if stud.fname == input_text %}  
        <td>{{stud.id}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.roll}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.sclass}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.fname}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.lname}}</td>
        {% endif %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %} 
    </tbody>
</table>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```